# Check if required fields are filled or not in SPList programmatically

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, spfield, splist

I want to check if required field in SharePoint list is filled with data or not? Which method or property should i use?

Answer (score 1):

While creating list you can mention which all fields are required. Then SharePoint will do the validation on out of the box add/edit forms.

If that is not the case then you can use a Event Reciever which handles ItemAdding event and do the validation. If validation fails you can cancel the event.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint will **not** do the validation if an item is added by code. It would be best to iterate through all the fields and if that field is not read only & required, check if it's value is null or not. I guess there is no built-in method how to do it. Your best bet would be something like this in an ItemAdding event receiver:

`foreach (SPField f in properties.ListItem.Fields)
{
   if (!f.ReadOnlyField && f.Required && properties.AfterProperties[f.InternalName] == null)
   {
      //cancel adding item
   }
}`